# System.FormatException: 'Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido

Tags: c#, sqlite

Olá, estou tentando atualizar dados de uma linha de um db sqlite, porém estou tendo problema em um campo de data.

Eu insiro dados no campo Registrado com o seguinte código, onde TB_Data_Cadastrado é um DateTimePicker:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Registrado", DbType.Date).Value = TB_Data_Cadastro.Value.Date;
```

Após inserir e consultando o banco de dados é salvo desta maneira: 2020-12-03 00:00:00

Porém, ao alterar qualquer linha com o seguinte comando o tipo de data muda:

```
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("UPDATE Produtos_TB SET Registrado = '" + TB_Data_Cadastro.Value.Date + "' WHERE ID = '" + id + "'");
```

E consultando o banco de dados no mesmo campo passar a ser: 3.12.20 00:00:00

Então a partir de quando a data fica nesse segundo formato (3.12.20) qualquer consulta ou algo que fizer no db me retorna esse erro:

```
System.FormatException: 'Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido.'
```

Dei uma pesquisada e olhei que o SQLite usa um tipo de data que é o yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, em base disso tentei formatar a data para a linha ser atualizada desse jeito, porém sem sucesso. Ao cadastrar vi que talvez seja feita uma conversão de System.DateTime para DBType.Date, porém não consegui aplicar algo parecido no meu código.

Comment: se você tem o parâmetro tipado  `@Registrado`, por que no `UPDATE` você está querendo concatenar diretamente o valor do DatePicker?

Comment: Ahhh é SQLite, tem que ser por string mesmo

Comment: Sim, eu ainda pesquisei outras formas de fazer o `UPDATE` porém é desta forma mesmo, creio que o problema seja que é inserido o formato de data que está configurado no computador e não no formato do SQLite. Vou continuar tentando resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O SQLite não tem um tipo específico para o armazenamento de datas como o SQLServer, por padrão elas são armazenadas com o tipo `Text` no formato string ISO8601. Então você precisa formatar o seu Date nesse formato.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
using (var command = new SqliteCommand())
{
    var dataFormatada = TB_Data_Cadastro.Value.Date
                            .ToString("s", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    
    command.Parameters.Add("@Registrado", SqliteType.Text).Value = dataFormatada;                
    command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqliteType.Integer).Value = 1;

    //command.Connection = {*SUA CONEXAO*}
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;                
    command.CommandText = 
         @"UPDATE Produtos_TB 
           SET Registrado = @Registrado
           WHERE Id = @Id";

    _ = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o erro, eu não sabia que poderia fazer o `UPDATE` da mesma forma que fiz o `INSERT`, porém eu usei o `DbType.String`.

Comment: Se você está usando o SQLite eu recomendo que use o Enum do tipo correto